# Why does Oracle Fusion BPM (Business Process management) quick start installation stuck at 49%?

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware

I have install the Oracle web logic server, SOA and setup Domain. Now I am trying to install the Oracle Fusion Middleware 12c Business Process Management Quick start. The installation progress stuck at generating Libraries (49%). I left it over night but it was still 49%.

I follow this [post][1] but its not show any solution. My error are exactly the same.

What I have checked;
I have checked all the version of Oracle installations which are same 12.2.1.3.0.
JDK is also 64 bit installed on windows server 2019 64 bit.
I have run the same process as administrator user but still stuck.
I have try clean the server and reinstall full setup again no success.

I dont have anything else to try but ask for Stackoverflow. Can you please tell me how can I find the core problem and how to fix this?
Please try to help me with this issue I just started Oracle. I really thanks full in advance.
[1]: https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/3946996/webcenter-portal-12c-installation-is-stopping-at-49

Answer (score 0):

When I run the setup prompt as administrator the process completed.